# Custom Keras Loss Function throws 'ValueError None'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

### This custom Keras Loss function:

```
def thresholdLoss (actual, predicted):
  rel = predicted / safeActual
  relAbove = tf.greater(rel, 1.50)
  relBelow = tf.less(rel, .50)
  isOutsideThresh = tf.logical_or(relAbove, relBelow, name='outsideRange')
  errCounts = tf.to_float(tf.count_nonzero(isOutsideThresh), name='countToFloat') 
  return errCounts
```

Throws the following exception in the call to fit():

```
ValueError: Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

### What causes `x` to be the value `None` in square(x) called by the rmsProp optimizer?

Edit: It is caused by a gradient of all None values.

### How can the loss function be modified to ensure a valid gradient?

as computed by Keras `gradients_impl.py:gradients()`?

Comment: We need to see all of your code and the entire error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the loss function not being continuous. It returns a count, rather than a smooth/continuously-varying, real-valued error.

Keras computes a gradient from the loss function. When that function is not continuous, Keras can return None values as the gradient vector. And this is the result of that cryptic error message.

So the problem is only with that final 'countToFloat' computation that reduces the error to a discontinuous count.

The solution is to compute a continuous error. Something like this:

```
delta = predicted - actual
withinBand = tf.logical_and(tf.greater_equal(rel, .50), tf.less_equal(rel, 1.50))
    err = tf.square(delta)
    err = tf.where(withinBand, .10 * tf.ones_like(actual), err)    # reduce relevance of small error
    mse = K.mean(err)
    return mse
```